# electrical feed to fish cleaning station

Tags: gfci, grounding-and-bonding, underground

I have a fish cleaning station with a light and a GFCI receptacle.  The GFCI feeds the outdoor floodlight that keeps tugboats from running into the pier.  Should the circuit be fed by a GFCI breaker. Past experience before Hurricane IKE took the house was that there was much nuisance tripping from the GFCI circuit breaker. The feeder is in underground plastic conduit, still much nuisance tripping.  Removal of the GFCI breaker has eliminated the nuisance tripping.  BTW, the breaker panel is bonded and it is the second panel so technically it's a sub panel.   Also, what is that official NEC word for that main panel?

Comment: This is just a comment, not an answer, but I believe that critical circuits that have nuisance tripping can be removed from GFCI protection.  I would certainly consider floodlights that prevent tugboats from running into things are critical!

Comment: I would think that the "lighthouse" portion of the lighting should be on a dedicated circuit to ensure that nothing short of a power failure interrupts the lights (maybe consider a battery/generator backup for this). Then the "fish cleaning station" would be on a different circuit so you can turn the work lights on/off. The outlets for this should probably be on yet another circuit that's GFCI protected, while the lights, presumably up high where they can't be touched might not have to be GFCI protected. That way if you trip the breaker, you're not left in the dark with a knife in your hands.

Comment: Welcome! Please clarify the breaker panel situation. Is that subpanel at the fish cleaning station, or at the pier, or at the house? Where is the main panel, and what specifically are you asking about it? It may be that you have multiple questions which should be divided into multiple posts. That's OK.

Comment: Greg, The main panel, 1st disconnecting place, with a 200 amp breaker, is at ground level in the garage, 2 feet from the meter.   the second panel with a 200 amp breaker is upstairs in the house with the many circuit breakers to operate the house, lights, receptacles, washer  air-conditioning etc. both panels are bonded. I intend to separate the ground and neutral in the panel upstairs.  Is that OK to do?

Answer (score 3):

### You're misusing a phrase there, "nuisance tripping".

You are using "nuisance trip" to describe *all* unwanted trips. *News flash: they're ALL unwanted*, so they doesn't really distinguish anything.

We are concerned with trips which occur because of a genuine safety hazard.  A string of good luck *so far* does not make a thing "not a hazard".

I'm not saying you 100% definitely had a hazard there. I'm saying *you didn't look*.  You just decided that detecting ground faults wasn't fun for you, and having the power stay on was more important than others' safety.

There are many reasons for GFCI trips at dockside. Some are genuine nuisance trips (dockside circuits tend to be long, and GFCI does have a practical circuit length limit.). There are also genuine hazards due to incompetent installation (such as using "Romex" NM-B or other cable not rated for the outdoor or underground application).

Because the problem is *so* well known and the solution is *so* easy, and it's been in Code for years... if there's a casualty you have *no* defense **for removing one**.  You're literally talking a one-way ticket to prison.

### Dealing with the tripping

Very long wiring problem: GFCIs can't tolerate extremely long circuits.  In this case, one can install "a receptacle on a post" or a disconnect or subpanel, along the circuit route but still significantly setback from the water. The GFCI(s) go there, so they are dealing with a shorter run.

Romex used improperly outside problem: Replace with wiring rated for the service, and fire whoever installed it, even if it's yourself. A person who botches one Code requirement will botch many, and dockside is no place to be fooling around.

Appliance or contaminated junction box having *actual genuine ground fault*: Hunt it down and deal with it.

Light can't be on GFCI for reliability reasons: Easy, step the light down to "low voltage". You do the "post some distance from the water" trick, put a GFCI there to feed the dockside outlets, then a 12V or 24V **isolating** transformer to power the safety light (the transformer primary is not on GFCI).  Use enormous aluminum cable like 2-2-2 SEU to carry the low voltage from the transformer to the light.  Ground the cable ground but leave the two low-voltage wires floating. If you can get a low voltage light great, otherwise step back up to 120/240V right inside the light enclosure using an isolating transformer. It would be very difficult for that to become energized at more than your low-voltage voltage.

Comment: Yeah, 12V waterproof lights shouldn't be hard to find at all, for one

Comment: Nowhere,  except in the conduit is there any wire not protected by a GFCI.  Does that matter?   I appreciate those replies and will put in a GFI breaker at the panel in the house to feed that run and see what happens.   Fairly certain it's not Romex, but will check today.

Comment: @ctaylor if you have a GFCI device (presumably a receptacle) at the very first point where the circuit arrives dockside, that is a "get out of jail free" card in the event a mishap does happen.  I would try to aim higher *myself* but Code does not require more.  If you already had the GFCI receptacle and had a GFCI breaker also, well that's just silly, *however, the fact that the GFCI breaker was tripping indicates a possible fault in the cable e.g. due to misuse of Romex there*.

Comment: Thank you Harper, "Aiming Higher" was the reason for asking. There is a GFCI receptacle where the circuit arrives at the fish cleaning station.  We call it the "speck spot".  the conduit runs up from the ground  on the post for any device that needs to be plugged in. It is NOT Romex but is the gray UF or UF-B in 3/4 inch PVC. The underground part of the run is less than 50 feet.

Comment: OK, so if you had a GFCI breaker feeding a GFCI receptacle, then the matter of concern is why the GFCI breaker tripped.  Either a faulty breaker or a cable problem. If you have any other GFCI breakers in the panel, I would move the circuit to a different GFCI breaker and see if it holds.